# PHP to exec casperjs/phantomjs script

Tags: php, node.js, macos, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm having trouble using PHP to execute a casperjs script:

```
<?php
putenv("PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");
var_dump(exec("echo \$PATH"));
exec("/usr/local/bin/casperjs hello.js website.com 2>&1",$output);
var_dump($output);
```

Which results in the following output:

```
string(43) "/usr/gnu/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:."
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(36) "env: node: No such file or directory"
}
```

The only stackoverflow posts I could find hinted that there's a problem with my paths, and that maybe the PHP user can't access what it needs.

I have also tried the following: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`

Does anyone know what I would need to do or change for this error to resolve?

Thanks

Comment: Have you by any chance defined `#/usr/bin/env node` as the first line of hello.js? CasperJS runs on the PhantomJS executions environment and not on node. Normally, there is no reference to node.

Comment: Thanks @ArtjomB. I'm not familiar with the line you provided. Should i just paste that at the top of the casper script?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. I don't know where the node reference comes from.

Comment: I'd remove that symlink, then work out where Node is getting called, and let us know here. Does Casper run on Node?

Comment: @halfer No, CasperJS runs on PhantomJS which itself has a distinct execution environment from node. Generally they can't share modules. CasperJS and PhantomJS are only installed through npm for convenience.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is you have something, somewhere, that assumes node is installed.

First, are you running php from the commandline? I.e. as `php test.php` in a bash shell. If so, you can run the commands, below, as they are. If through a web server the environment can be different. I'd start with making a [`phpinfo();` script](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php), and then run the troubleshooting commands through `shell_exec()` commands. But, as that is a pain, I'd get it working from the commandline first, and only mess around with this if the behaviour is different when run through a web server. (BTW, if you are running from a cron job, again, the environment can be slightly different. But only worry about this if it works from commandline but does not work from cron.)

**Troubleshoot hello.js**

The easy one. Make sure your script does not refer to `node` anywhere. Also remember you cannot use node modules. So look for `require()` commands that should not be there.

**Troubleshoot your bash shell**

Run `printenv | grep -i node` to see if anything is there. But when PHP runs a shell command, some other files get run too. So check what is in `/etc/profile` and `~/.bash_profile` . Also check `/etc/profile.d/`, `/etc/bashrc` and `~/.bashrc`. You're basically looking for anything that mentions `node`.

**Troubleshoot phantomjs/casperjs**

How did you install phantomjs and casperjs? Are the actual binaries under /usr/local/bin, or symlinks, or are they bash scripts to the . E.g. on my machine:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
ls -l casperjs phantomjs
```

gives:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 darren darren 36 Apr 29  2014 casperjs -> /usr/local/src/casperjs/bin/casperjs
lrwxrwxrwx 1 darren darren 57 Apr 29  2014 phantomjs -> /usr/local/src/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs
```

And then to check each file:

```
head /usr/local/src/casperjs/bin/casperjs
head /usr/local/src/phantomjs-1.9.7-linux-x86_64/bin/phantomjs
```

The first tells me casper is actually a python script `#!/usr/bin/env python`, while the second fills the screen with junk, telling me it is a binary executable.